# Improve performance on loop with increasing window to calculate area between curves

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I'd like to find a way to improve performance on this function.

Basically it gives the area between two curves with an increasing window.

At each iteration the `range_x` used for the integration is longer until it reaches the hole length of the first vector.

```
library(sfsmisc) # for integrate.xy()

area_function = function(x, y_curve1, y_curve2) {
  y_betw = rep(0, x) # the first value needs to be 0, it changes from the 2nd and so on.
  # this loop goes from 2:length(y)
    for (i in seq_along(y_curve1)[-1]) {
      y_range1 = y_curve1[1:i]
      y_range2 = y_curve2[1:i]
      range_x = 1:length(y_range1)

      y_betw[i] = integrate.xy(range_x, y_range2) - integrate.xy(range_x, y_range1)
    }
  return(y_betw)
}
```

Reproducible example with results:

```
set.seed(123)
v1 <- sample(100, 100) # first curve
v2 <- sample(100, 100) # second curve

head(area_function(length(v1), v1, v2), 5)
#[1]   0.00000  -7.50000 -48.66658 -29.62492 -49.95353
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a spline to integrate on? default `use.spline = TRUE`... this gives varying results for each increasing range...

Comment: I did not think of that, thanks I'll be sure to look into it. Anyway my concern is more about the loop part with the increasing window, the integrate function could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
area_function = function(y_curve1, y_curve2) {
  dv <- y_curve2 - y_curve1
  return(cumsum(dv) - dv[1]/2 - dv/2)
}
```

Not sure I understand the purpose of `x` so I have discarded it. This integration makes use of trapesium rule. Using the built in base function `cumsum` is very fast. Then you need to take away half of the first value and half of the value at the point of interest.

Comment: This is brilliant, I really over thought the process.

Comment: Actually, my solution seems to differ in the result after the second number. not sure why

Comment: I checked and it's the exact same solution, looks good to me.

Comment: It is due to the use.spline, when this is set to false the solution is identical.